# Why different substances have different specific heat capacities?

Tags: thermodynamics

Specific heat capacity depends upon the nature of the substance. But i want to know, in what way?

Temperature is defined as the average kinetic energy of the molecules. So,for a given mass, a sample of element having lower atomic mass will have more number  of molecules than the element having higher atomic mass. If equal heat is provided to both the samples, because of difference in the number of molecules, the average kinetic energy will become more for the one which has less number of molecules. Thus the element having lower atomic mass has higher specific heat capacity. Is it a valid/complete generalization?

Comment: Hi Nabin. That's really too broad a question to be usefully answered here. You need to do some background research in this area and come back to us with any more specific questions.

Comment: @JohnRennie *specific* questions.

Comment: Temperature is not defined as the average kinetic energy of molecules. That's only the case for an ideal gas.

Comment: @Javier - The kinetic pressure tensor can be defined by the second velocity moment regardless of the type of gas.  The relation to kinetic temperature depends upon the equation of state of the system, which may not permit a simple linear relationship I agree.  But is it really true that the second velocity moment has no relation to temperature for non-ideal gases?